# How to show the links to the category with Django

Tags: django

I'm coding a bookmark project to learn Django. I want to show the links belonging to the category. but when I run the for loop, the categories are shown twice and the card design is sorted one under the other instead of side by side. I think the problem is with the index.html file. I think I need to use if command but I don't know how.

index.html:

```html
<!-- component -->
<div class="bg-gray-100">
    <div class="container mx-auto">
        <div role="article" class="bg-gray-100 py-12 md:px-8">
            <div class="px-4 xl:px-0 py-10">
                <div class="flex flex-col lg:flex-row flex-wrap">
                    <div class="mt-4 lg:mt-0 lg:w-3/5">
                        <div>
                            <h1 class="text-3xl ml-2 lg:ml-0 lg:text-4xl font-bold text-gray-900 tracking-normal lg:w-11/12">Lorem ipsum</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lg:w-2/5 flex mt-10 ml-2 lg:ml-0 lg:mt-0 lg:justify-end">
                        <div class="pt-2 relative text-gray-600">
                            <input class="focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-gray-400 bg-white h-10 px-5 pr-16 rounded-lg text-sm focus:outline-none" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" />
                            <button type="submit" class="focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 text-gray-600 focus:text-indigo-700 focus:rounded-full focus:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-indigo-700 bg-white focus:outline-none absolute right-0 top-0 mt-5 mr-4">
                                <svg class="h-4 w-4 fill-current" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 56.966 56.966" style="enable-background: new 0 0 56.966 56.966" xml:space="preserve" width="512px" height="512px">
                                    <path d="M55.146,51.887L41.588,37.786c3.486-4.144,5.396-9.358,5.396-14.786c0-12.682-10.318-23-23-23s-23,10.318-23,23  s10.318,23,23,23c4.761,0,9.298-1.436,13.177-4.162l13.661,14.208c0.571,0.593,1.339,0.92,2.162,0.92  c0.779,0,1.518-0.297,2.079-0.837C56.255,54.982,56.293,53.08,55.146,51.887z M23.984,6c9.374,0,17,7.626,17,17s-7.626,17-17,17  s-17-7.626-17-17S14.61,6,23.984,6z" />
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
<!--index.html-->
<!--===============================================================-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

{% comment %} Add a <div> node INSIDE the first 'for' loop {% endcomment %}
{% for category in categories %}
    <div class="col-4">

      <!--Card code goes here; remember, you don't want 3 'for' loops;
          just 2!-->

      <div class="px-6 xl:px-0">
        <div class="grid sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-3 pb-6 gap-8">
          <div role="cell" class="bg-gray-100">
            <div class="bg-white p-5 rounded-md relative h-full w-full">
              <h1 class="pb-4 text-2xl font-semibold">
                {{ category.name }}
              </h1>
    
              

{% comment %} The nested 'for' loop goes through each bookmark that is 
related to the category on this card is dedicated to {% endcomment %}

              {% for bookmark in category.bookmarks_set.all %}
              <div class="my-5">
                <div class="flex items-center pb-4 dark:border-gray-700 cursor-pointer w-full space-x-3">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12.5" height="16" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 5l7 7-7 7" />
                  </svg>
                  <a href="{{bookmark.link}}">
                    <h4 class="text-md text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" title="{{bookmark.description}}">
                      {{bookmark.title}}
                    </h4>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              {% endfor %}        
              <div>
              <a class="hover:text-indigo-500 hover:underline absolute bottom-5 text-sm text-indigo-700 font-bold cursor-pointer flex items-center" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <p>Show All</p>
                <div>
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-arrow-narrow-right" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#4338CA" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                    <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                    <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12" />
                    <line x1="15" y1="16" x2="19" y2="12" />
                    <line x1="15" y1="8" x2="19" y2="12" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </a>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
{% endfor %}

  </div>
</div>





<!--component end-->
```

views.py:

```py
def index(request):
        bookmark_list = Bookmarks.objects.all()
        return render(request,"index.html",{'bookmark_list':bookmark_list})
```

models.py:

```py
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        def __str__(self):
                return self.name

        class Meta:
                db_table = ''
                managed = True
                verbose_name = 'Category'
                verbose_name_plural = 'Categorys'


# Create your models here.

class Bookmarks(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField( max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000,blank=True)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=400)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't coded in Django in some time, so forgive me if I just correct your spelling... it's "categories", not "categorys."

Comment: no problem. which page?

Comment: It's the line `verbose_name_plural = 'Categorys'`

Answer (score 0):

I think I see two separate issues:

## 1. Displaying All Bookmark Links on Same Card, Grouped by Categories

You can use a set of nested `{% for %}` loops in order to achieve this. Right now, you are passing `bookmarks` as an object to the template, which is fine, but makes it difficult to group by category. You can access the related set of `Bookmarks` from each `Category` much more easily. I recommend changing your `views.py` to something like the following:

```py
# views.py
#=====================================================================
def index(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request,"index.html",{'categories':categories})
```

Then, inside your template, you can set up your nested loop like this:

```html
<!--index.html-->
<!--===============================================================-->
{% comment %} The first 'for' loop makes a card with the category's 
name as a heading {% endcomment %}

{% for category in categories %}
<div class="px-6 xl:px-0">
  <div class="grid sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-3 pb-6 gap-8">
    <div role="cell" class="bg-gray-100">
      <div class="bg-white p-5 rounded-md relative h-full w-full">
        <h1 class="pb-4 text-2xl font-semibold">{{ category.name }}</h1>

{% comment %} The nested 'for' loop goes through each bookmark that is 
related to the category on this card is dedicated to {% endcomment %}

        {% for bookmark in category.bookmark_set.all %}
        <div class="my-5">
          <div class="flex items-center pb-4 dark:border-gray-700 cursor-pointer w-full space-x-3">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12.5" height="16" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 5l7 7-7 7" />
            </svg>
            <a href="{{bookmark.link}}">
              <h4 class="text-md text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" title="{{bookmark.description}}">
                {{bookmark.title}}
              </h4>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}        

        <a class="hover:text-indigo-500 hover:underline absolute bottom-5 text-sm text-indigo-700 font-bold cursor-pointer flex items-center" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <p>Show All</p>
          <div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-arrow-narrow-right" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#4338CA" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
              <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
              <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12" />
              <line x1="15" y1="16" x2="19" y2="12" />
              <line x1="15" y1="8" x2="19" y2="12" />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Basically, `category.bookmark_set.all` uses the foreign key relationship to get a filtered list of all the bookmarks related to the given category. The Django documentation talks more about how this works here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls

### Shortcomings

Based on your `models.py`, if you have a `Bookmark` with a null foreign key, it will not be rendered, since not only does it not belong to a `Category`, it doesn't have a relationship to `Category` at all. One way to handle this would be to create a catch-all `Category` called "None" or something. Then you can add a `default` pointing to your "None" category's `pk` to `Bookmark.category`. This would mean that even if a bookmark were created without the user explicitly creating a category, it would be assigned to the "None" category automatically.

Also, since `on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING` for your `Bookmark`, if you delete the `Category` a `Bookmark` belongs to, the `Bookmark` will not render because it will have a relationship to a `Category` that doesn't exist. This can cause problems with database integrity. Since your `Bookmark.category` can be set to null, I recommend (at the very least) setting `on_delete = models.SET_NULL` instead. If you decide to go with the catch-all "None" Category, I'd set `on_delete = models.SET(<pk>)`, where `<pk>` is the primary key of the "None" `Category`. If you decided to add a default value for your `Bookmark.category`, you could also set `on_delete = models.SET_DEFAULT`. You can read more about these in the Django documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

## 2. Laying Out Cards from Left to Right

I'm not sure which framework you are using for your HTML classes, but the reason your layout isn't working the way you want almost definitely lies there. If you are using Bootstrap, you can do the following; if not, hopefully this helps guide you to how you can accomplish the same thing.

Bootstrap uses a 12-column grid-style system for layouts. You should be able to get your cards to display left-to-right in three columns by doing the following:

```html
<!--index.html-->
<!--===============================================================-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

{% comment %} Add a <div> node INSIDE the first 'for' loop {% endcomment %}
{% for category in categories %}
    <div class="col-4">

      <!--Card code goes here; remember, you don't want 3 'for' loops;
          just 2!-->

      <div class="px-6 xl:px-0">
        <div class="grid sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-3 pb-6 gap-8">
          <div role="cell" class="bg-gray-100">
            <div class="bg-white p-5 rounded-md relative h-full w-full">
              <h1 class="pb-4 text-2xl font-semibold">
                {{ category.name }}
              </h1>

{% comment %} The nested 'for' loop goes through each bookmark that is 
related to the category on this card is dedicated to {% endcomment %}

              {% for bookmark in category.bookmark_set.all %}
              <div class="my-5">
                <div class="flex items-center pb-4 dark:border-gray-700 cursor-pointer w-full space-x-3">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12.5" height="16" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 5l7 7-7 7" />
                  </svg>
                  <a href="{{bookmark.link}}">
                    <h4 class="text-md text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" title="{{bookmark.description}}">
                      {{bookmark.title}}
                    </h4>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              {% endfor %}        

              <a class="hover:text-indigo-500 hover:underline absolute bottom-5 text-sm text-indigo-700 font-bold cursor-pointer flex items-center" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <p>Show All</p>
                <div>
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-arrow-narrow-right" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#4338CA" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                    <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                    <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12" />
                    <line x1="15" y1="16" x2="19" y2="12" />
                    <line x1="15" y1="8" x2="19" y2="12" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </a>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
{% endfor %}

  </div>
</div>
```

The `col-4` class forces a column that is 4 of Bootstrap's 12 columns wide. This means that no matter the screen width, there will always be 3 columns on screen. It looks like you are trying to create a responsive page that reduces the number of columns based on the screen size; Bootstrap's documentation covers how to do that here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/

You don't have to use Bootstrap (and this isn't a plug for them in any way), I'm just most familiar with how to setup a layout like this using Bootstrap. It looks like the `grid` class on one of the `<div>` nodes is what does something similar to this; whatever framework you're using probably documents a way to force a left-to-right-then-down (vs. top-to-bottom-then-right) layout scheme.

Comment: As an aside, if you're curious about how the `{% if %}` tag works, the documentation is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if

Comment: Thanks, I solved the category issue. but still the card design is not side by side but one under the other. I use tailwind. I edited the index html. In short, I use this component.
https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/free-tailwind-css-404-page-component

Comment: Hmm... I've never used Tailwind, but the docs talk about "Grid Auto Flow"... You could try adding the `grid-flow-row` class to the same `<div>` that has the `grid` class. That might work. Docs I'm looking at are here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-auto-flow